# How to set Development environment in V.S.Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am using V.S Code to develop an Asp.net Core project. I tried to set the environment to "Development" by setting it in cmd line with 
`setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"`
or/and changing settings in Launch.json with

```
"env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
```

as showed in the attached picture below, but seems the environment is still "Production". Did I miss anything? Thanks!

[Setting "Development" in V.S Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOY2A.jpg)

Comment: Can you check if you ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to "Production" in environment variables on your machine?

Comment: Check the *launchSettings.json* file in the Properties folder of the application. Specifically, in the `environmentVariables` settings. That may be overriding anything in the environment variables.

Comment: @R.Richards launchSettings.json only works with Visual Studio and it is mentioned in the question that Visual Studio Code is being used. So checking launchSettings.json is out of quesiton

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Not true. When I run `dotnet run` for a webapi or mvc application I just created, this is the output I see the console: `Using launch settings from <path>\Properties\launchSettings.json...`. Same for `dotnet watch run`.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Do you know how to check this variable? I typed "set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" and it replied with "Environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" not defined.

Comment: @R.Richards seems there is not a launchSettings.json file under the project folder.

Comment: Is there a *Properties* folder? That is where the file will be. What version of dotnet are you running? 1.1, 2.0, or something else?

Comment: @R.Richards I am using v2.1.200, I guess it is the latest version. There is no folder named Properties.

Comment: That explains that. :) Try this: `dotnet watch run --environment "Development"` at the command line.

Comment: @R.Richards "When I run dotnet run for a webapi or mvc application I just created, this is the output I see the console: Using launch settings from <path>\Properties\launchSettings.json.... Same for dotnet watch run" Do you run it using Visual Studio Code?

Comment: So my findings are that when a new asp.net core web application is created using cli `dotnet new web` there is no Properties folder created and no launchSettings.json. However, when a project is created using Visual Studio a properties folder with launchSettings.json will be created. However, when there is a requirement to debug application using Visual Studio code `launch.json` file is added

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I am running the command from a Power Shell prompt from within VS Code, just like the OP is. Turns out, if that file isn't present, the default environment will be Production. If it is there, `dotnet run` will use it. Setting the env variable should work. Strange that it doesn't.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood My findings when creating a new core web application using `dotnet new web`: there *is* a *Properties* folder created, and a *launchSettings.json* file. I am using `dotnet --version` -> 2.1.300.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood It is really strange, I used the cmd line `dotnet watch run --environment "Development"`as you suggested, but still got the same "Production" mode. This is a business laptop from a company, is any chance the administrator set the updates of environment variables disabled?

Comment: @AmyZeng for setting the environment variable check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Thank you very much for the information. Today I checked the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, it became "Development". And the variable is "Development" in the environment variable lists when I followed the instruction in the article you gave. Perhaps what I needed was restarting my computer. I restarted the v.s.code for many times the other day but not the computer. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables will not take effect if we run directly from the terminal.

Instead, click the "Run and Debug" menu on the left and chose the name of the configuration profile where the environmental variables are added, then click the "Run" icon.